# Shell Script output contains multiple words

Tags: shell, if-statement, contains, multiple-conditions

I am trying to create a script in which I am running a command which gives a output. I am interested in few words in the output, I am using following script:

```
cfservices=$(cf services)<br/>
if [[ $cfservices == *"postgres...."* ]]; then<br/>
echo " done "<br/>
else<br/>
echo " fail "
```

but this helps find only one word. Please help me find multiple words.

Answer (score 0):

You could use grep to find both:

```
cf services | grep postgres | grep mongo
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
  echo " done"
else
  echo " fail "
fi
```

Comment: If i want to search for postgres and also mongo then how to achieve this?